# Cannot create slots-dataclass with __dict__

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

In python, it is possible to create slots classes which do have an explicit `__dict__` available. However, I am struggling to get this working with dataclasses:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(slots=True)
class A:
    __dict__: dict[str, object]

A()
```

This raises the following on the last line:

> TypeError: __dict__ must be set to a dictionary, not a 'mappingproxy'

It is not even clear to me where this exception actually occurs since there is no further information provided. There also seems to be no information regarding this problem on google. What is the problem here? How do I create a slots-dataclass with a `__dict__`?

Comment: Interesting. They must've changed the error at some point. I get an error on the class declaration line (not the construction line) stating `ValueError: mutable default <class 'mappingproxy'> for field __dict__ is not allowed: use default_factory`. I'm running Python 3.11. What did you test this on?

Comment: FWIW combining slots and dict, on regular classes gave a *partial* memory saving when I looked at it, if thats your goal.  Leaner than standard dict based classes.  Heavier than slots only classes.  By no means is it “have cake and eat it”.

Comment: I don't see why this should be even expected to actually work. Does not data-classes skip any field starting with `_` to start with? And if it does not, `__dict__` would befit from special treatment in the generated `__init__` that probably is not coded there as an edge-case. 
One will really have to open `dataclass.py` source, debug what takes place with this combination, and try to come out with a workaround.

Comment: @JLPeyret I definitely need a `__dict__` because the class has `functools.cached_property`s. But it seems I cannot make it a slots dataclass then.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo python 3.10.10. (Using `default_factory` does not actually solve the problem, it creates the same error message.)

Comment: @HerpDerpington My point wasn't to say you didn't need dict, it was to say you might not gain that much from using slots, if that was your motivation.  By itself slots save a fair bit of memory, at the cost of some hassles.  Worth it in some cases, maybe.  But adding dict back in will lose a good deal of those gains, leaving you with slots based hassles (you are seeing one!) but not all that much gained memory.  Now, you may have other reasons to use slots, I dunno.  I generally have learned to avoid them, too many edge cases.  would namedtuple be helpful?